# Create simple Html.DropDownList or DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

I am trying to include a list of Clients in a drop down box. I am including this list in a form (the Html.BeginForm()) so that I can pass the selected value to my POST controller. I think I am missing something, I have the following classes:

my Invoice ViewModel:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public InvoiceViewModel()
    {
        // makes sure InvoiceItems is not null after construction
        InvoiceItems = new List<PrelimInvoice>();
    }
    public List<PrelimInvoice> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public List<Client> ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```

My Client Model:

```
public class Client
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My SaveInvoice method:

```
public ActionResult SaveInvoice()
        {
            var invoice = new Invoice();
            TryUpdateModel(invoice);
            try
            {
                    invoice.ClientId = User.Identity.Name;
                    invoice.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                    //Save invoice
                    proent.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                    proent.SaveChanges();
                    //Process the invoice
                    var preliminvoice = InvoiceLogic.GetInvoice(this.HttpContext);
                    preliminvoice.CreateInvoice(invoice);

                    return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = invoice.InvoiceId });
            }
            catch
            {
                //Invalid - redisplay with errors
                return View(invoice);
            }
        }
```

And my Index.cshtml is strongly typed to the InvoiceViewModel class.
Index.cshtml is where I generate the form.

I am not sure of the code for creating the Html.DropDownList, and whether or not I need to include a List or something of my Clients. I have dropdownlists in other places but they are strongly typed to models, not viewmodels, hence my confusion.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Show us your controller action method code, please.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the one you want to see, and please bear in mind I have not built the form or added the Http Post annotation to the method yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by adding to your ViewModel the following 2 properties:

1. SelectedClientId: which stores the selected value
2. ClientItems: stores the collection of SelectListItems which populates your drop down.

E.G.

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    public List<Client> Clients;

    public int SelectedClientId { get; set; } // from point 1 above
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientItems // point 2 above
    {
        get { return new SelectList(Clients, "Id", "Name");}
    }
}
```

Then on your View index.cshtml you would add the following:

```
@model ClientViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedClientId, Model.ClientItems)
```